# Cannot simplicity convert type 'string[]' to 'Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am making a custom view in Xamarin.Forms that inherit from a custom renderer (a camera) in Xamarin.IOS.
After finishing it now I am trying to pass an array of strings containing the multiple clips recorded from the custom renderer in Xamarin.IOS to the custom View in the common folder so I can use it in the ViewModel.
This is what I tried:

Camera view:

```
namespace Project.Renderers
{
    public enum CameraOptions
    {
        Rear,
        Front
    }

    public class CameraView : View
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CameraProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Camera), typeof(CameraOptions), typeof(CameraView), CameraOptions.Rear);
        public static BindableProperty clipsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Clips), typeof(string[]), typeof(CameraView), null);

        public CameraOptions Camera
        {
            get { return (CameraOptions)GetValue(CameraProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CameraProperty, value); }
        }

        public string[] Clips
        {
            get { return (string[])GetValue(clipsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(clipsProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

In my IOS renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CameraView), typeof(CameraViewRenderer))]
namespace Project.iOS.Renderers
{
    //ViewRenderer<X,Y>: Y is the native renderer from which the custom one (X) will inherit.
    public class CameraViewRenderer: ViewRenderer<CameraView, NativeCameraView>
    {
        NativeCameraView uiCameraPreview;

        public CameraViewRenderer()
        {
            //This is where the conflict happens
            CameraView.clipsProperty = new string[] {""};
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to set a value in the renderer I get the following error: 'Cannot simplicity convert type 'string[]' to 'Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty'.

This is the first time I try to create a custom renderer so chances are I am making a simple mistake, yet I can't see how to solve it.

Any idea about how can I send this array of strings back to my custom view?

Comment: shouldn't you be doing `CameraView.Clips = new string[] {""};`

Comment: @Jason the ViewRenderer only reads BindableProperties from the View, at least in my example. I can do that from the xaml.cs file, but not from the ViewRenderer.

Comment: What's the `NativeCameraView` and `CameraView`  In your `CameraViewRenderer`? Can you elaborate on that?